# Pyraf building wrong version of gcc on os x

Tags: python, macos, gcc

I have installed python 2.7 through enthought 7.2 package, i've been trying to install pyraf package, however everytime i try to install it i got the following:

```
copying lib/pyraf/wutil.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/pyraf
running build_ext
building 'pyraf.sscanfmodule' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -isysroot
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -isysroot
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
-I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/include/python2.7
-I/usr/X11R6/include
-I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/include/python2.7 -c
src/sscanfmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So i thought it was an architecture issue, so i reinstalled packages (i386, XCode) and then got this

```
running install
running build
running build_py
copying lib/pyraf/svn_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/pyraf
running build_ext
building 'pyraf.sscanfmodule' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -isysroot         
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -isysroot     
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -    
I/usr/X11R6/include -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -c 
src/sscanfmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
```

Afterwards it seemed to me that the real problem was a gcc version problem, so i looked for any gcc installed, i found this:

```
Last login: Wed Feb 29 11:06:40 on ttys009
Giotto:~ Huguito$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
Giotto:~ Huguito$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0/4.6.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.0/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.0 (GCC) 

gcc-4.2

alias gcc="/usr//bin/gcc-4.2"

Giotto:~ Huguito$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc

Giotto:~ Huguito$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-
werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --    
program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-
apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --    
target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

gcc-4.0:

alias gcc="/usr//bin/gcc-4.0"

Giotto:~ Huguito$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc

Giotto:~ Huguito$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc_40/gcc_40-5494~315/src/configure --disable-checking -
enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --
program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.0/ --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.0.0 
--with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-arch=apple --with-
tune=generic --host=i686-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5494)
```

so i decided with an alias line in my .bash_profile file pointing out to the correct gcc version, it didn't work at all.

I tried setting up gcc environment and building the pyraf setup.py and got this:

```
Giotto:pyraf-dev Huguito$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

Giotto:pyraf-dev Huguito$ python setup.py build


running build
running build_py
copying lib/pyraf/svn_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/pyraf
running build_ext
building 'pyraf.sscanfmodule' extension
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -isysroot 
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -isysroot     
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -
I/usr/X11R6/include -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -c 
src/sscanfmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g -arch i386 build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-
2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/pyraf/sscanfmodule.so
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

If i type the gcc command but without the -arch i386 flags:

```
Giotto:pyraf-dev Huguito$ gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot 
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk 
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -
I/usr/X11R6/include -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -c 
src/sscanfmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o
```

it seems to compile fine, however after recompiling it ignores it and dosen't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

try it.
install Command Line Tools from your Xcode. in Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components ->Command Line Tools